# Unit Testing functions within repository interfaces - ASP.net MVC3 & Moq

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing, testing, moq

I'm getting into writing unit testing and have implemented a nice repository pattern/moq to allow me to test my functions without using "real" data. So far so good.. However..

In my repository interface for "Posts" `IPostRepository` I have a function:
`Post getPostByID(int id);`
I want to be able to test this from my Test class but cannot work out how.

So far I am using this pattern for my tests:

```
[SetUp]
public void Setup()
{
    mock = new Mock<IPostRepository>();
}

[Test]
public void someTest()
{
    populate(10);  //This populates the mock with 10 fake entries

    //do test here
}
```

In my function "someTest" I want to be able to call/test the function `GetPostById`. I can find the function with `mock.object.getpostbyid` but the "object" is null.

Any help would be appreciated :)

iPostRepository:

```
public interface IPostRepository
{
    IQueryable<Post> Posts {get;}

    void SavePost(Post post);
    Post getPostByID(int id);
}
```

Comment: How does `populate(10)` create the data?  Getting a null reference exception on the `object` property of the mock usually means the mock isn't instantiated, but it looks like you're doing that in `[SetUp]`.  It might be worth making sure that `[SetUp]` is running as expected.

Comment: Oh, I think I understand now--I read "object" is null and I thought you meant the `object` property of the Mock.  I think Marnix has your answer

Comment: @ataddeini Yeah, the populate just iterates, adding to the mock to save me writing the same 10 lines in every test-case!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your mock object to return a result (not null), you need to set it up:

```
mock.Setup( m => m.GetPostByID( 5 ) ).Returns( new Post() );
```

What you return exactly is up to you of course.

**Update:**

If you need to use the method parameters you can also setup a [CallBack](http://code.google.com/p/moq/wiki/QuickStart#Callbacks). For example:

```
mock.Setup( m => m.GetPostByID( It.IsAny<int>() ) )
    .Callback( id => return new Post{ Id = id; } );
```

This may make your setup code much easier since you don't need to prime the mock with data.

Comment: Dam! I was so close with my idea, I did this but didn't know about the returns() function! I'll look at this later :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what unit testing framework you are using, but I am using NUnit.  I'm not a unit testing pro, but I know enough to get me started and to get results.

I normally have a service layer, and this will call my post repository:

```
public class PostService
{
     private readonly IPostRepository postRepository;

     public PostService(IPostRepository postRepository)
     {
          if (postRepository== null)
          {
               throw new ArgumentNullException("postRepository cannot be null.", "postRepository");
          }

          this.postRepository = postRepository;
     }

     public Post GetPostById(int id)
     {
          return postRepository.GetPostById(id);
     }
}
```

Your unit tests could look like this:

```
[TestFixture]
public class PostServiceTests
{
     private PostService sut;
     private Mock<IPostRepository> postRepositoryMock;
     private Post post;

     [SetUp]
     public void Setup()
     {
          postRepositoryMock = new Mock<IPostRepository>();

          sut = new PostService(postRepositoryMock.Object);

          post = new Post
          {
               Id = 5
          };
     }

     [Test]
     public void GetPostById_should_call_repository_to_get_a_post_by_id()
     {
          int id = 5;
          postRepositoryMock
               .Setup(x => x.GetPostById(id))
               .Returns(post).Verifiable();

          // Act
          Post result = sut.GetPostById(id);

          // Assert
          Assert.AreEqual(post, result);
          postRepositoryMock.Verify();
     }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Tried a selection of these ideas over the weekend and this one is pretty nice! I'll be using it in the future!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test the real implementation of `GetPostById`, do so via the real implementation of `IPostRepository`. Moq (and mocks in general) are only for situation where you don't want to use the real thing.

In other words prime your database with some posts, new up the real repository, call `GetPostById` and make assertions on the result. This is not strictly a unit test though, but an integration test because it includes the database.